# Spark-Scala: Get Dataframe Variable by concatenating two String Variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where I need to form a dataframe name from two string variable. Which is pretty easy and can be done by concatenating.

Example: "df_" + "part1324"

The above code will return a String variable. I want this to be a Dataframe variable through which I can perform further operation on the data frame.

Comment: It would be great if questions are supported with the code, that has been tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map can be used for assign names to DataFrames:

```
val df = List(("df_value")).toDF()
val stringVariable = "part1324"

// assign name to dataframe
val namedDataFrames = Map("df_" + stringVariable -> df)

// get dataframe by name
namedDataFrames("df_part1324").show(false)
```

Comment: Although, I am really curious to know about the memory usage. Say if I am having a lot of data frames. Each with millions of record. How will the Map variable holding all those Dataframe variables impact memory usage, if any?

Comment: Map will contains only pointers to DataFrames, not DataFrames data; means, Map memory usage will be very small.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. What do you mean by dataframe variable? Concatenating two strings will always return String. In order to create a dataframe, you need to apply the different methods available to create a dataframe.

val df:Dataframe cannot be equal to df_part1234 (String)as per your example but to use it as dataframe, you need to do something like below

val df_part1234 = sc.range(1000).toDF("number") where sc is your Sparksession variable.

In case you need to generate this variable dynamically, place it under the logic of variable generation like Loop and add the statement to create the dataframe.

Please rewrite your question if you are trying to achieve something else (along with code snippet to reproduce the issue) or accept the answer if you are clear on the issue